# Retrieve object with specific name

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I am building a dashboard where input is a list of stock name. When the user chooses the stock name, it show a plot.

This plot is constructed using a data frame that is already made.

For eg. If the user choose APPL. It has to find the object named APPL from the global environment.

```
 output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$ticker)
    series <- find(input$ticker) 
    splot <- plot(series$date, series$technical, type = 'l', xlab = "Date", ylab = "Tech")
    splot
```

I know "find" is the wrong function to use. Any help would be appreciated.

Alternatively, I can export all the object and import as the user choose. Then it would be

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$ticker)
    stockticker <- input$ticker
    stockticker <- paste(stockticker, ".xlsx", sep = "")
    series <- read_excel(stockticker, coltype = c("date", "numeric") 
    splot <- plot(series$date, series$technical, type = 'l', xlab = "Date", ylab = "Tech")
    splot
```

This works, but I would like to not export anywhere as I want to host it online in the future. So if someone can point out how I can find and save an object with it's name, that would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `get`, i.e. `series <- get(input$ticker)`. However, personally I would suggest to store all the objects in a (named) list or in one dataframe.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for.
I'm just prototyping for now. In my final version, I am going to put all the dataframe into one master list and get the value from there. Thank you so much for the help